# Response length for APL Audio Source

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Document says below for APL Audio:

> Response length – The combined total time for the entire audio
> response generated from the components can't be more than 240 seconds.

Source: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-presentation-language/apla-audio.html

However, my mp3 file is **5 minute** long (more then 240 second) and it plays within my APL audio source element without any problems. could it be i am testing it in Dev environment?

what did i miss?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, this may be due to using the dev version. Please note that the requirements in the testing console are slightly more accessible than on the devices. I tested some of my audios that didn't meet the requirements just as an example, the audio extension, bit rate, etc. and it worked. Normally it plays even if it does not meet all the requirements, but better to fix this for the final version.

Comment: I am testing it on Actual Fire TV with a display. But yes, skill is not live yet.